# Is "final static variables " efficient in Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, static, final, c-preprocessor

I'm developing an app in Android. I use a lot `"final static"` variables to define my constants. But I'm very stric with the memory used by my application.

Maybe I have 200 constants (int, string, double, ...). It is much better to program with constant variables that use numbers. But, how efficient is this?

Using C I can use `#define`, and when I put:

```
#define constant 10
int var2 = constant;
int var3 = constant;
```

The compiler translates the code to:

```
int var2 = 10;
int var3 = 10;
```

But using Java, I think that all these variables stay in memory. There is something so efficient as `#define` for java?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html. check the link.

Comment: Specifically http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#UseFinal

Comment: final static it's way to create a constant in java

Comment: *"But using Java, I think that all these variables stay in memory"* ... and that's different from your C example, how? I don't think you quite understand what the preprocessor macro is doing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835283/performance-differences-between-static-and-non-static-final-primitive-fields-in

And

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496629/do-static-members-help-memory-efficiency

Comment: I think the compiler makes the sustitution, anyway 200 integers/doubles is not something to be worried about. Do not try to hiper-optimize, it is not worth it (somebody said that premature optimization is the mother of 90% of all evils, or something like that...)

Comment: There's a reason the people from whom you copy and pasted this posted it as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use something similar to C's `ifdef` you should do something like:

```
final static boolean COMPILE_THIS = false;
```

This will cause the following code not to be part of your program ("compiled"):

```
if (COMPILE_THIS) {
   printToScreen("HELLO");
}
```

Google uses this technique a lot in the Android code when they don't want to "compile" parts of it.